# How to allow users to ssh when sftp enabled

Tags: ssh, login, nfs, sftp

We have an nfs share which is mounted to `/mnt/logs`.
User A is found within group sftp (in active directory) and can only sftp to /mnt/logs. In sshd_config we have:

```
Match Group sftpgr
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Directory /mnt/logs has the following permissions: `drwxrwxr-x userX sftp`

User A can sftp to /mnt/logs

Now we have another user, User B which can ssh to the host machine. Once we add User B to sftp group in active directory User B can no longer ssh.

How do we allow a group of users to sftp only to the /mnt/logs folder whilst allowing other users to ssh and access(and delete) files within /mnt/logs .

setfacl is not working with nfs.

Comment: Please provide your `sshd_config` from the server. (Add it to your question, and use `{}` to mark it as code.) I would imagine you've a directive in there that restricts access to users in the group `sftp`.

Comment: (1) `sftpgr` vs `sftp`. Is this right? (2) What is the home directory for user A? and for user B?

Comment: If you’re really using 2 different groups (`sftpgr` and `sftp`), I think it should work as expected if User A is member of both groups while User B is member of `sftp` only.